# How can I import a csv (using COPY command) into PostgreSQL on an EC2 instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have postgres running on an ec2 instance. I have scp'd a csv file into the ec2 instance.

`ls` shows the .csv file is there.

Then, once in the psql shell, I try to run the normal COPY command to import the csv like I normally do from my local machine. However I get an error saying 'No such file or directory'.

What is the correct file path to my csv file from within the psql shell? How can I access/point to this file from within the psql shell?

Comment: Have you tried giving it the full path to the file? The documentation says `filename` is: _"The path name of the input or output file. An input file name can be an absolute or relative path, but an output file name must be an absolute path. Windows users might need to use an `E''` string and double any backslashes used in the path name."_